# Simple word game using TCP socket

Tags: python, tcp

I'm new to socket and python programming, and I'm trying to build a simple game between server and client. Basically server types in a word and the client tries to guess another word starting with the first two letters of the server's word.Example: *Server:computer|Client:erase|Server:secondary|Client:rye*
I've got a loop that takes messages from client and sends it back to it and vice versa:

```
#server.py
while True:
   message_sent = input(str("Me : "))
   conn.send(message_sent.encode())
   message_received = conn.recv(1024).decode()
   first = message_sent[:2]
   last = message_received[-2:]
   print(s_name, ":", message_received)
   if first != last:
       message = "wrong word entered "
       conn.send(message.encode())
       print("\n")
       break
```

and client.py:

```
#client.py
while True:
   message_received = s.recv(1024).decode()
   print(s_name, ":", message_received)
   message_sent = input(str("Me : "))

   first = message_sent[:2]
   last = message_received[-2:]
   if first != last:
      message = "wrong word typed "
      s.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   s.send(message_sent.encode())
```

when I send an incorrect word to the server from the client I can get the "wrong word typed" but when I send it other way it just accepts the word and keeps going. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if the client inputs an incorrect word, u dont want it to be sent to the server, and u want the client to keep typing words untill it gets a correct one?

Comment: no I just want to finish the game there and declare a winner

Comment: Neither client not server checks if response contains "wrong word". They should check that if it is true, end the game.

Comment: "but when I send it other way it just accepts the word and keeps going." what do u mean by that? who sends what to who, and what does it look like when it 'keeps going' can u give an example?

Comment: when I meant "wrong word" I meant a word that's not following the rules of the game. which I'm trying to do in the if block, checking the first two letters of the message to be sent and checking the last two letters of the message that been received

Comment: @richie I meant when I send a string from the client to the server it lets me keep sending messages to the other side even if I sent a word that's not following the rules of the game

Comment: u didnt send the incorrect word u sent "wrong word typed " to the server or "wrong word entered " to the client. like @johnnyMopp said, u need to check for those strings, and if recieved end the game

Answer (score 0):

in the server add:

```
while True:
   message_sent = input(str("Me : "))
   conn.send(message_sent.encode())
   message_received = conn.recv(1024).decode()
   if message_received == "wrongword":
       print('GAME OVER')
       print('Winner is Server')
       break
   first = message_sent[:2]
   last = message_received[-2:]
   print(s_name, ":", message_received)
   if first != last:
       message = "wrongword"
       conn.send(message.encode())
       print("\n")
       break
```

in the client:

```
while True:
   message_received = s.recv(1024).decode()
   if message_received == "wrongword":
       print('GAME OVER')
       print('Winner is Client')
       break
   print(s_name, ":", message_received)
   message_sent = input(str("Me : "))

   first = message_sent[:2]
   last = message_received[-2:]
   if first != last:
      message = "wrongword"
      s.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   s.send(message_sent.encode())
```

Comment: here is the output of the program https://hizliresim.com/61m00k btw the first word was computer on the server side. I think there is a logic error in my own block but I can't seem to understand how?

Comment: try with the edit? for some reason the code in the server didnt enter this condition: if message_received == "wrong word typed ". maybe cus of the space i left out.

Comment: the reason that I've write wrongword in the terminal to show you that when I enter a word that does not follow the game rules it still keeps going even if a wrong word not "wrongword"

Comment: i understand, i was just wondering why that was the case, so i changed the condition hoping it would fix the problem, did it? its a shot in the dark, cus i dont understand why the first code didnt work, i assume it was the space character i left in the string

Comment: in the servers code it should enter this condition if message_received == "wrongword" and break from teh while loop. it doesnt do that, even when it prints that it got the string "wrongword" in message_received. if u debug the servers code, check why that isnt the case. maybe some hidden character that doesnt show in the print or something